# Why does komodo edit require a duplicate .py file to execute my commands?

Tags: komodo

I am using Komodo edit 7.1 on a macbook pro running OS X mountain lion

Note that the duplicated file needs a space at the beginning. e.g: 
to execute hello-world.py, I wrote the code given in the lesson but when running the command i get an error 
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/pythonhello-world.py: No such file or directory.

When I create a file name: _hello-world.py (the underscore is actually white space) and execute it from there, the command completes the action correctly
'/usr/bin/python hello-world.py' returned 0.

Interestingly enough, the code for the duplicated file can be blank, somehow it is choosing the proper file.

p.s. obviously I am brand new at this. I have searched google for similar problems but haven't found what I need. Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The path to the python executable is not setup correctly. Use the [Terminal](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/gettingstarted.html#macosx) to fix it.